# Error : Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list' (codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I am getting this error

> Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

When inserting checkbox list into database. When I do **print_array** I am getting this result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 3
            [project_id] => 10
            [project_type] => 5
            [project_list] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 17
                    [1] => 18
                )

        )

)
```

The `project_list` value supposed to be inserted into a new row in the database.

**my view** : `<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $project_list['id']; ?>" name="project_list[]">` which is populated from database.

**my controller** : `$this->Project_module->createProject($_POST['project_list']);`

**my module**

```
public function createProject($project_list){

    if($project_list != null){

        $data = array();

        foreach($project_list as $project_list){
            $data[] = array(
                'user_id'          => $this->getUserId(),
                'project_id'       => $this->getProjectId(),
                'project_type'     => $this->getProjectType(),
                'project_list'     => $this->getProjectList(),
            );
        }

        $this->db->insert_batch('tblProject', $data);

        if($this->db->affected_rows()){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    } 

}
```

**EDIT**
I was edited my foreach like this

```
foreach($project_list as $row){
    $data = array(
        'user_id'          => $this->getUserId(),
        'project_id'       => $this->getProjectId(),
        'project_type'     => $this->getProjectType(),
        'project_list'     => $this->getProjectList(),
    );
}
```

But I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Inside your foreach just add `$data` not `$data[]` and change your foreach variable

Comment: @Nawin I changed it but still the same error.

Comment: $this->getProjectList() returns an array and you are trying to put that array in your DB as a field. So implode(',' , $this->getProjectList()) would fix it, but you may want to save them in another table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already pass the project_list So you don't want to get the list again. And you can store the just `foreach` string. In my side confusion with `$data` and `$data[]` So test with both and let me know.... 
**Please check before with Table fields are correct**

```
public function createProject($project_list){

    if($project_list != null){

        $data = array();

        foreach($project_list as $row){
            $data[] = array(
                'user_id'          => $this->getUserId(),
                'project_id'       => $this->getProjectId(),
                'project_type'     => $this->getProjectType(),
                'project_list'     => $row,
            );
        }

        $this->db->insert_batch('tblProject', $data);

        if($this->db->affected_rows()){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    } 

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Linundus, you need to name the array alias in the foreach something different. You have

```
foreach ($project_list as $project_list)
```

you need to have something like this:

```
foreach($project_list as $list)
```

Comment: I changed my variable but still getting the error. check my edited question. thank you

Comment: Where is $project_list coming from? Can you var_dump and provide an example of the array structure?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem and here is my coding that working fine now.

**ERROR CAUSE**

In the **controller** I have already set the checkbox setter like this :

`$this->Project_module->setProjectList($this->input->post('project_list'));`

and then call the `createProject` function after like this :

`$this->Project_module->createProject($_POST['project_list']);`

So I am getting error with the foreach inside my module.

**SOLUTION**

**In controller**

1. Remove this line

   `$this->Project_module->setProjectList($this->input->post('project_list'));`
2. Simply hold all checkbox value in line

   `$this->Project_module->createProject($_POST['project_list']);`

**And in module**

```
public function createProject($project_list){   // $_POST['project_list'] value pass in $project_list

    if($project_list != null){

        $data = array();

        foreach($project_list as $row){         // Do foreach to insert every value in different rows in database
            $data[] = array(
                'user_id'          => $this->getUserId(),
                'project_id'       => $this->getProjectId(),
                'project_type'     => $this->getProjectType(),
                'project_list'     => $row,
            );
        }
        
        $this->db->insert_batch('tblProject', $data);
        
        if($this->db->affected_rows()){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    } 

}
```

Comment: You didn't mention this line in your question so we don't know `$this->Project_module->setProjectList($this->input->post('project_list'));`

Comment: @Nawin yes and sorry about that. I did not realize it

Answer (score 0):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 3
            [project_id] => 10
            [project_type] => 5
            [project_list] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 17
                    [1] => 18
                )

        )

)
```

your value is in a nested key 0  so if you want to access project_id  you'll have to use  `$array[0]['project_id']`

a suggestion here would be to you check if values inside key 0  exist then do print